# Attach parameter to button.addTarget action in Swift

Tags: swift, button, uibutton

I am trying to pass an extra parameter to the buttonClicked action, but cannot work out what the syntax should be in Swift.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Any my buttonClicked method:

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    println("hello")
}
```

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39584022/898057) for a detailed answer and best practice

Comment: The question doesn't have a good answer because it already describes a problematic architecture. You don't need an extra parameter. The need for a n additional parameter is a problem in your architecture.

Comment: `WARNING TO INTERNET: please check out my answer at the bottom`

Comment: You can pass parameters in newer Swift versions by using `addAction`, which is much more flexible than `addTarget`, see example below

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You cannot pass custom parameters in `addTarget:`.One alternative is set the `tag` property of button and do work based on the tag.

```
button.tag = 5
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", 
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Or for *Swift 2.2* and greater:

```
button.tag = 5
button.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonClicked),
    forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

Now do logic based on `tag` property

```
@objc func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    if(sender.tag == 5){

        var abc = "argOne" //Do something for tag 5
    }
    print("hello")
}
```

Comment: Hi, If i want to get indexPath or cell of button in tableView, is it possible?

Comment: Here's a hint: Don't make the method private.

Comment: Seems like it's type only can be an `Int`. Nothing else.

Comment: what if I want to pass row and section together?

Comment: just so you know, despite 118 upvotes (and counting) this is the wrong way to do this

Answer (score 86):

If you want to send additional parameters to the buttonClicked method, for example an indexPath or urlString, you can subclass the UIButton:

```
class SubclassedUIButton: UIButton {
    var indexPath: Int?
    var urlString: String?
}
```

Make sure to change the button's class in the identity inspector to subclassedUIButton.  You can access the parameters inside the buttonClicked method using `sender.indexPath` or `sender.urlString`.

Note: If your button is inside a cell you can set the value of these additional parameters in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method (where the button is created).

Comment: This was the only way that worked for me. But I'm curious, is this anti-pattern or not?

Comment: This is the best way, I think

Answer (score 36):

I appreciate everyone saying use tags, but really you need to extend the UIButton class and simply add the object there..

Tags are a hopeless way round this. Extend the UIButton like this (in Swift 4)

```
import UIKit
class PassableUIButton: UIButton{
    var params: Dictionary<String, Any>
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.params = [:]
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.params = [:]
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

then your call may be call (NOTE THE colon ":" in `Selector(("webButtonTouched:"))`)

```
let webButton = PassableUIButton(frame: CGRect(x:310, y:40, width:40, height:40))
webButton.setTitle("Visit",for: .normal)
webButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.webButtonTouched(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)
webButton.params["myvalue"] = "bob"
```

then finally catch it all here

```
@IBAction func webButtonTouched(_ sender: PassableUIButton) {
    print(sender.params["myvalue"] ?? "")
}
```

You do this one time and use it throughout your project (you can even make the child class have a generic "object" and put whatever you like into the button!). Or use the example above to put an inexhaustible number of key/string params into the button.. Really useful for including things like urls, confirm message methodology etc

*As an aside, it's important that the `SO` community realise this there is an entire generation of bad practice being cut'n'paste round the internet by an alarming number of programmers who don't understand/haven't been taught/missed the point of the concept of `object extensions`*

Comment: Can anyone comment whether this is the correct way to do this or not?

Comment: @Eric33187 It's a correct and, moreover, cleaner object oriented approach. But using tags is a lazy in place solution. They both work, but using tags - smells

Answer (score 10):

For Swift 3.0 you can use following

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.YourMethodName(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)

func YourMethodName(_ sender : UIButton) {
    print(sender.tag)

}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4.2**

Result:

```
testButton.on(.touchUpInside) { (sender, event) in
    // You can use any reference initialized before the code block here
    // You can access self by adding [weak self] before (sender, event)
    // You can then either make self strong by using a guard statement or use a optional operator (?)
    print("user did press test button")
}
```

In the file `UIButton+Events.swift` I've created an extension method for `UIButton` that binds a `UIControl.Event` to a completion handler called `EventHandler`:

```
import UIKit

fileprivate var bindedEvents: [UIButton:EventBinder] = [:]

fileprivate class EventBinder {

    let event: UIControl.Event
    let button: UIButton
    let handler: UIButton.EventHandler
    let selector: Selector

    required init(
        _ event: UIControl.Event,
        on button: UIButton,
        withHandler handler: @escaping UIButton.EventHandler
    ) {
        self.event = event
        self.button = button
        self.handler = handler
        self.selector = #selector(performEvent(on:ofType:))
        button.addTarget(self, action: self.selector, for: event)
    }

    deinit {
        button.removeTarget(self, action: selector, for: event)
        if let index = bindedEvents.index(forKey: button) {
            bindedEvents.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}

private extension EventBinder {

    @objc func performEvent(on sender: UIButton, ofType event: UIControl.Event) {
        handler(sender, event)
    }
}

extension UIButton {

    typealias EventHandler = (UIButton, UIControl.Event) -> Void

    func on(_ event: UIControl.Event, handler: @escaping EventHandler) {
        bindedEvents[self] = EventBinder(event, on: self, withHandler: handler)
    }
}
```

The reason why I used a custom class for binding the event is to be able to dispose the reference later when the button is deintialised. This will prevent a possible memory leak from occurring. This wasn't possible within the `UIButton` its extension, because I'm not allowed to implement a property nor the `deinit` method.

Answer (score 2):

**If you have a loop of buttons like me you can try something like this**

```
var buttonTags:[Int:String]? // can be [Int:Any]
let myArray = [0:"a",1:"b"]
for (index,value) in myArray {

     let button = // Create a button

     buttonTags?[index] = myArray[index]
     button.tag = index
     button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchDown)

}
@objc func buttonAction(_ sender:UIButton) {

    let myString = buttonTags[sender.tag]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.0 code (Here we go again)**

The called action should marked like this because that is the syntax for swift function for exporting functions into objective c language.

```
@objc func deleteAction(sender: UIButton) {
}
```

create some working button:

```
let deleteButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
deleteButton.setTitle("Delete", for: [])
deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector( 
MyController.deleteAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This works, but marking it with @objc feels unintuitive. Can you explain the reasoning for this?

Comment: @rawbee Agree that this is counterintuitive. This question has more background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390378/how-can-i-deal-with-objc-inference-deprecation-with-selector-in-swift-4?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5.0 code

I use theButton.tag but if i have plenty type of option, its be very long switch case.

```
theButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(theFunc), for: .touchUpInside) 
theButton.frame.name = "myParameter"
```

.

```
@objc func theFunc(sender:UIButton){ 
print(sender.frame.name)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an important comment. Sharing references of sytanx that is acceptable out of the box. For hack solutions look at other answers.

[Per Apple's docs, Action Method Definitions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol#1943645) have to be either one of these three. Anything else is unaccepted.

```
@IBAction func doSomething()
@IBAction func doSomething(sender: UIButton)
@IBAction func doSomething(sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent)
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 2.X and above**

```
button.addTarget(self,action:#selector(YourControllerName.buttonClicked(_:)),
                         forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0 code**

```
self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector:#selector(fetchAutocompletePlaces(timer:)), userInfo:[textView.text], repeats: true)

func fetchAutocompletePlaces(timer : Timer) {

  let keyword = timer.userInfo
}
```

You can send value in 'userinfo' and use that as parameter in the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", 
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

Button tag may help you to retrieve dedicated records from the array/dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Although you can not pass a parameter the way you propose (With `addTarget`), you can use the `addAction`, where you can call any other function with any parameters you want:

```
let btnAuto = UIButton(type: .system)
    btnAuto.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0 , width:200, height:20)
    btnAuto.backgroundColor = .blue
    btnAuto.addAction(
        UIAction { _ in
            print("This gets printed when the button is pressed")
            dothis(param1, param2)
        }, for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(btnAuto)
```

This is specially useful when you programmatically create a series of buttons and you want each of them to do a different action.

Comment: iOS 14.0 or greater is required for this solution

Answer (score -1):

May be overkill, but couldn't you use a protocol for this? Then there would really be no need to pass in a parameter because you should have access to the properties within the conforming class.

```
protocol ButtonActionDelegate {
      func buttonClicked()
}

class SomeClassWithSomeButton: ButtonActionDelegate {
      let button = UIButton
      button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

      func buttonClicked() {
           //Do specific action
          }
}
```