# Swift 2 - Send Object to function

Tags: uitextfield, swift2

How can I send another object to `textFieldDidChange` function?

```
    regName.delegate = self

    regName.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField, errorLabel: UILabel) {

        validateReg(textField.text!, textField: textField, errorLabel: errorLabel)
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach parameter to button.addTarget action in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814646/attach-parameter-to-button-addtarget-action-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot do this