# How to send additional parameter in addtarget function?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

please anyone tell me, How to send additional parameter in addtarget function in swift 2.2?
Example:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(classname.myFunc(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside))

func myFunc(sender:UIButton){
    print(“i am here“)
}
```

to

```
func myFunc(sender:UIButton,parameter:String){
    print(“i am here“)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach parameter to button.addTarget action in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814646/attach-parameter-to-button-addtarget-action-in-swift)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a subclass of `UIButton`, add one property named `parameter` which you want to pass as an extra parameter.

In `addTarget()`, you can only choose passing the caller or not. In this case, the caller is a `UIButton`.

So use the subclass and call `addTarget()`, then you can get the string which you want send:

```
func myFunc(sender: customUIButton) {
    // do something with sender.parameter
}
```

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 2.2** you can do something like this.

```
myUISlider.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.onSliderValChanged(_:withEvent:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

func onSliderValChanged(slider: UISlider, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `sender` properties to send some parameters with it like

```
button.accessibilityHint = "param 1"
button.accessibilityValue = "param 2"
button.tag = 0

button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)),   forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside))

func myFunc(sender:UIButton){

 print(sender.accessibilityHint) // param1
 print(sender.accessibilityValue) // param2
 print(sender.tag) // 0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You have to use a workaround.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(classname.myFunc(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside))

func myFunc(sender:UIButton){
    self.myFunc2(sender, parameter: "My parameter")
}

func myFunc2(sender:UIButton,parameter:String){
}
```

Comment: This wont solve the issue unless the parameter is a global varibale. If that was the case then we didnt need to pass the parameter itself. Selector can only provide the caller as sender. Nothing more.

Comment: @kandelvijaya What issue are you referring to? OP didn't mention any. Anyway, it's possible OP wants to call `myFunc2` with string X when button1 is tapped, and `myFunc2` with string Y when button2 is tapped. So there is nothing wrong with this design.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.0 code

```
theButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(theFunc), for: .touchUpInside) 
theButton.frame.name = "myParameter"
```

.

```
@objc func theFunc(sender:UIButton){ 
print(sender.frame.name)
}
```