# How to write selector that takes an argument in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, selector

In Swift 2 this used to work (I have left out table view methods intentionally)...

```
 import Foundation
 import UIKit

 private extension Selector {
    static let didTapButton = #selector(TableVC.buttonTapped(_ :))

 }

 class TableVC: UITableViewController{

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         let btnAccView:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 27))
         btnAccView.addTarget(self, action: .didTapButton, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
         btnAccView.tag = indexPath.row
     }


     func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton){
         print("button tapped at row \(sender.tag)")
     }

 }
```

In Swift 3 this causes the error : "TableVC has no member buttonTapped".

I just need to write a selector that takes an argument.
I have tried fiddling with the syntax in every way I can think of but nothing has worked. Thanks for your help

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24814646/5513562)'s answer, it can't be done.

Comment: http://fuckingclosuresyntax.com/
http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/

Comment: Just for the record, marking a question as a duplicate and not referencing the original question is of absolutely no use to anyone.  If it's a duplicate where is the original?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to modify `buttonTapped` so that the first argument label is suppressed.  Insert an underscore before the internal argument label so that it looks like this:

```
func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

Before, its method signature was `TableVC.buttonTapped(sender:)`, and now its signature will be `TableVC.buttonTapped(_:)`.  You might have to remove the space between the underscore and the colon in your extension, but it should work after that.

As a side note, is there any particular reason you're using an extension on `Selector` here?  That extension model is most useful typically with stuff like notification names that can be easily misspelled, resulting in tricky bugs.  Since the Swift compiler automatically validates `#selector` declarations no matter where they're placed, you can just put it right into your code—no extension necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself some grief by letting the compiler infer some of the function signature. In your case...

```
class TableVC: UIViewController {
    func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) { /*...*/ }
}
```

You can refer to it from outside the `TableVC` class as either:

- `#selector(TableVC.buttonTapped(sender:))`
- `#selector(TableVC.buttonTapped)`

The second works because there's only one `buttonTapped` function on `TableVC`, so the compiler doesn't need the full signature to disambiguate it.

From code inside of `TableVC` you can simplify it a step further and just use `#selector(buttonTapped)`, because at that point you're in the class scope and it can safely infer a method of the class.

(The `#selector(TableVC.buttonTapped(_:))` line you're using works only if your method is declared as `func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)`. For your use case, it doesn't matter whether the `sender` parameter has an argument label or not — you just have to be consistent about it between your `func` declaration and your `#selector` expression.)

And as @Bob notes, there's no need for the `Selector` extension, because the compiler already validates the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use following way to implement selector for button action:

```
import UIKit
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))

    override init?(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        let action = #selector(MyViewController.tappedButton)
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: action, forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)
    }

    func tappedButton(sender: UIButton?) {
        print("tapped button")
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```