# Swift: how to add params in button.addTarget

Tags: swift, selector, addtarget

I have a func below, but can`t send href for func.

```
func someFunc() {
    linkBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(headerClick(_:href:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return headerView
}

@objc func headerClick(_ sender: AnyObject, href: String) {
    print(href)
}
```

Comment: you can only get the sender parameter I believe. what are you trying to pass to your handler function?

Comment: You can't add params through the addTarget. You should implement protocol in order to pass the params.

Comment: @ChristianAbella I am trying to pass diff type for show diff controller.  so that this button can responds to different requests

Comment: refer to this for an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814646/attach-parameter-to-button-addtarget-action-in-swift

Comment: @Nizzam so .. I need to extension my button only ?~

Answer (score 0):

Custom your button:

```
class LinkButton: UIButton {
  var href: String?
}
```

in your function:

```
func someFunc() {
  linkBtn.href = yourHref
  linkBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleClink(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
@objc func handleClick(_ sender: LinkButton) {
  if let href = sender.href{
    print(href)
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Now PLEASE add some explanation as to WHY this is a good answer! We are here to help not *just* the person asking something, we are trying to help others!